# In R, what is the difference between class ts and class timeSeries?

Tags: r, time-series

In R, what is the difference between class `ts` and class `timeSeries`? I think I am getting a problem in `HoltWinters` because of that. I'm getting:

```
data(LakeHuron)
x <- LakeHuron
before <- window(x, end=1935)
after <- window(x, start=1935)
a <- .2
b <- 0
g <- 0
model <- HoltWinters(before, alpha=a, beta=b, gamma=g)
```

> "Error in decompose(ts(x[1L:wind], start = start(x), frequency = f), seasonal) : 
>     time series has no or less than 2 periods"

even though `gamma=0`.

Running R 2.11.1 (win32 x86) on a Windows 7 x64 machine.

Comment: could you please add the code you're running? Just an error message is not that informative...

Comment: Joris: here's the code: > data(LakeHuron)
> x <- LakeHuron
> before <- window(x, end=1935)
> after <- window(x, start=1935)
> a <- .2
> b <- 0
> g <- 0
> model <- HoltWinters(
+   before, 
+   alpha=a, beta=b, gamma=g)
Error in decompose(ts(x[1L:wind], start = start(x), frequency = f), seasonal) : 
  time series has no or less than 2 periods
but I found what the problem is. When gamma=0 and there is no seasonal component, the HoltWinters function expects it to be logical!! (see my answer)

Answer (score 4):

`ts` comes from the `stats` package included with base R.  It is useful for *regular* time series such as monthly, quarterly, annual, ... series common in goverment statistics.  `ts` is used by `arima()` and other time series methods provided by base R and its `stats` packages. `HoltWinters` which you used here is one such example.

`timeSeries` is one of many add-on time series classes; this one comes from [Rmetrics](http://www.Rmetrics.org).  Several [CRAN Task Views](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views) discuss these more: [TimeSeries](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html), [Econometrics](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Econometrics.html) as well as [Finance](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Finance.html).

Try the documentation on `ts` and/or `HoltWinters` to come to grips with the required format.  `ts` uses either a fixed *delta* (eg 1/12 for monthly data) or *frequency*.

Answer (score 4):

I've found the problem, studying the HoltWinters source code.
It turns out that the HoltWinters function, (for gamma=0, and if there is no seasonal component), expects gamma to be logical!! (zero = FALSE)

So, entering gamma as.logical(0) solves the bug.

Joris: thank you for the answer, that was illuminating.

Comment: I suggest you study the documentation instead.  Regarding `gamma`, `?HoltWinters` says: "gamma: gamma parameter used for the seasonal component.  If set to 'FALSE', an non-seasonal model is fitted."  This is not a bug, it is documented behavior!  Why are you surprised that it expects `gamma` to be logical when the documentation says so?

Answer (score 3):

It's two separate classes. `ts` is contained in the basic R installation, and the function `HoltWinters()` demands a `ts` time series.

`timeSeries` has a completely different structure. It's also specifically directed towards finances. The big difference with ts is that it allows for irregular timeseries. The class `ts` can only hold equispaced series.

Internally, ts has a slot "tsp" which contains the start, end and frequency of the timeseries.

```
> test <- ts(1:10, frequency = 4, start = c(1959, 2))
> slotNames(test)
[1] ".Data"    "tsp"      ".S3Class"
> slot(test,"tsp")
[1] 1959.25 1961.50    4.00
```

It's this slot that `HoltWinters()` needs but lacks in timeSeries. There the information on the times is contained in two slots, a position slot and a format slot. Together they define the times as a `timeDate` object.

```
> data = as.matrix(MSFT[, 4])
>    charvec = rownames(MSFT)
>    Close = timeSeries(data, charvec, units = "Close")
> slotNames(Close)
[1] ".Data"         "units"         "positions"     "format"        "FinCenter"     "recordIDs"     "title"         "documentation"
> head(slot(Close,"positions"))
[1] 970012800 970099200 970185600 970444800 970531200 970617600
> slot(Close,"format")
[1] "%Y-%m-%d"
```