# In R, how can you use Holt-Winters smoothing for a financial ("business-day")-based time series?

Tags: r, time-series

In R, how can you use Holt-Winters smoothing for a financial ("business-day")-based time series?

(For example, a stock data time series has an irregular time index).

Comment: I think this question might be a good candidate for http://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

You don't, for the reasons I gave you in response to your [previous question today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847270/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-class-ts-and-class-timeseries): because `HoltWinters` needs `ts`, you cannot (easily) use it on irregular time series.

You can approximate it by, say, sampling every Wednesday and creating 52-week years from that.  But there is no way around the basic fact that "business day"-based series are irregular.

Comment: you can easily by modelling the irregular time series without a seasonal component, i.e. setting gamma=FALSE, as OP answered himself in his previous question. That's a valid HoltWinters model.

Comment: @Dirk How can we write the holtwinter function for implementing `lines(HoltWinters(nhtemp, gamma=F)$fitted[,2], col = "red")` if we are restricted to use `holtwinters` function? Any hint is really appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As Dirk said there is no solid way to do this. Even if it runs (gamma=F) it will use a fixed gain on each observation, that is, it will ignore the fact that a week-end is 3 times longer than your other delta times.

It gets worse with intraday data. I think your best bet is to implement the Holt Winters filter yourself. It's actually not all that hard...